# iOS swift why two type of closure can't add to an array

Tags: ios, swift, closures

```
let sum1 = {(a:Int, b:Int) -> Int in return a + b}
let sum2 = {(a:Float, b:Float) -> Float in return a + b}

var cl = [sum1, sum2]
```

Why `sum1` and `sum2` can't be added to an array?
I know `sum1` takes two Ints return an Int, `sum2` takes two Floats return a Float, but an array can be added two different type of object, for example `let foo = [12, "12"]` is valid.

Comment: Is the error about the types in the array or the missing arguments of the closures for example `let cl = [sum1(1, 2), sum2(3.0, 4.0)]` ?

Comment: It says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: If you want to hold closures which are actualy the different types then mark your array of type any `let sum1 = {(a:Int, b:Int) -> Int in return a + b}
let sum2 = {(a:Float, b:Float) -> Float in return a + b}
var cl:[Any] = [sum1,sum2]`

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions that you use `[Any]` for this will compile, but if you need `Any` (or `AnyObject`) in a property, you almost always have a design mistake. `Any` exists for rare cases where you really must circumvent the type system, but you will typically run into numerous headaches with it.

There are numerous type-safe solutions to these kinds of problems depending on what your underlying goal really is. The most likely solution, if your goal is to keep Int-methods separate from Float-methods, is to use an enum:

```
enum Operator {
    case int((Int, Int) -> Int)
    case float((Float, Float) -> Float)
}

let sum1 = Operator.int {(a, b) in return a + b }
let sum2 = Operator.float {(a, b) in return a + b}

let cl = [sumop1, sumop2]
```

`Any` means you can throw absolutely anything in it and it's your problem to figure out what to do with the random things you find in it. The compiler can't help you, and in some cases will actively fight you. You'll need to accept undefined behavior or add `precondition` all over the place to check at runtime that you didn't make a mistake.

`Operator` is an "OR" type. `[Operator]` is an array of functions that either operate on Ints or Floats. This seems what you mean, so let the compiler help you by telling it that's what you mean. The compiler will detect mistakes at compile time rather than crashing at runtime. Many unit tests become unnecessary because whole classes of bugs are impossible. With a proper type and the compiler's help, you can simplify `cl` to:

```
let cl: [Operator] = [.int(+), .float(+)]
```

That's pretty nice IMO.

On the other hand, if the goal is to accept both Ints and Floats, then you should likely wrap them up in NSNumber which can work on both. If you want to keep track of which were Ints and which were Floats so you can apply your math more carefully, you can create a struct:

```
struct Number {
    enum Kind {
        case Int
        case Float
    }
    let value: NSNumber
    let type: Kind
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that each closure represents new type, and if your array is not of type `Any` or `AnyObject` than it can have inside only elements of one type. That's why you can't place them as easily inside. For Closures you need to use type `Any`, because closures is structure type.

Comment: thanks for answering!But even the type is AnyObject, I can't add the closure to the array

Comment: Try type Any. AnyObject can accept only classes, closures instead in not a class representation, it's structures.

Comment: ```var cl = [Any]()
cl.append(sum1)
cl.append(sum2)```
Thanks, this works!
It is only explicitly add to an array of type ```Any```